# Flutter - Could not build the precompiled application for the device

Tags: flutter, ssh

I work on my project by connecting through `ssh` on my mac. I try to run the app from `guest` but I get the following error:

```
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): Target debug_ios_bundle_flutter_assets failed: Exception: Failed to codesign <path>/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/App.framework/App with identity 5DA0CF2F8353F08A14F98B289B5D86614E6E7A55.
```

What is weird is that I tried to run the app directly from the `host` and it actually works but when I run from `guest` I get the above error.

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, it seems that the problem is related to keychain being locked, that being said I just unlock it with `security unlock-keychain -p <YourPassword> ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain` and the build works

[answer](https://superuser.com/a/363840)